# Do I need to report income for a non-profit Japanese club in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, accounting, non-profit

I'm setting up a Japanese club for kids in London, UK. The idea is that parents would pay into a community account and we would hire native speakers to run lessons/events, rent out a venue, etc. The club itself wouldn't make any money, and any teachers we hire would be self-employed and responsible for their own taxes.

My question is, do I need to report the club's income to HMRC? To the best of my understanding I don't think we do but I'd be very grateful for any advice or to hear about other people's experiences setting up similar entities.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.resourcecentre.org.uk/information-category/starting-a-group/

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks @Vicky